# how to set no proxy in httpclient like we set in Firefox network settings?

Tags: java, apache, proxy, httpclient, wcs

How do I set no proxy in httpclient like we set in Firefox network settings?

I have set java network settings to default browser setting in control panel and why its also not reflected?

For me a 3rd party service call is working in restclient for no proxy and timeout when I set office proxy. Below exception is there when I invoked from IBM WCS code.

```
[2/2/16 14:49:27:613 CET] 0000000a SystemErr     R java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
[2/2/16 14:49:27:614 CET] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
[2/2/16 14:49:27:615 CET] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:412)
[2/2/16 14:49:27:615 CET] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:271)
[2/2/16 14:49:27:615 CET] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:258)
[2/2/16 14:49:27:616 CET] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:376)
[2/2/16 14:49:27:616 CET] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:546)
[2/2/16 14:49:27:616 CET] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:567)
[2/2/16 14:49:27:616 CET] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:184)
[2/2/16 14:49:27:617 CET] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:1)
[2/2/16 14:49:27:617 CET] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.websphere.ssl.protocol.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:654)
[2/2/16 14:49:27:617 CET] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:82)
[2/2/16 14:49:27:618 CET] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:127)
[2/2/16 14:49:27:619 CET] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
[2/2/16 14:49:27:619 CET] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
[2/2/16 14:49:27:619 CET] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
[2/2/16 14:49:27:619 CET] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
[2/2/16 14:49:27:620 CET] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set domains to not go through the proxy in WAS by:

Go into the WAS admin console, select application servers-> YourServer mine is server1-> Java and process management -> process definition -> Java Virtual Machine -> Custom proprties

The create the property called http.nonProxyHosts and for the value put the domain you do not want to pass through the proxy server.

Answer (score -1):

**Reference:** https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientProxyAuthentication.java

I hope that it helps you to connect through your proxy server.

Comment: I need to bypass my office proxy. how is this going to help it?

Comment: Ideally, the IBM WCS server is deployed in the server environment that will not use office proxy.

I assume that you are developing an application in your office network and later you tried to test it in server environment and you have this issue.